# Why is my code throwing a C6386 error when trying to copy a character array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

i am getting a c++ warning C6386 on the following code:

```
int m_wordNumber = getRandomNumber();
//get word size
size_t m_wordSize = strlen(m_wordsArray[m_wordNumber]);
//create word arrays
char* m_chosenWord = new char[m_wordSize];
char* m_blankArray = new char[m_wordSize];

int m_incorrectGuessCounter = 0;

generateArray(m_blankArray, m_wordSize);
//copy word to new array
strcpy_s(m_chosenWord, m_wordSize + 1, m_wordsArray[m_wordNumber]);
//create temp array and output word
char * m_tempWordHolder = nullptr;
std::cout << m_chosenWord << std::endl;
```

The line that is throwing the warning is the strcpy_s line, all it's trying to do is copy a string from a character array to a different character array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

the warning is as follows:

> Warning   C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'm_chosenWord':  the writable size is 'm_wordSize*1' bytes, but '7' bytes might be written

Comment: what is C6386 ? Please include the error message in the question. Error codes are compiler specific, the error itself not. Not everybody uses visual studio

Comment: is it a warning or an error? Please provide a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: appologies, it is a warning that follows:
Warning C6386 Buffer overrun while writing to 'm_chosenWord':  the writable size is 'm_wordSize*1' bytes, but '7' bytes might be written.

Comment: any reason you are not using `std::string`?

Comment: ***char* m_chosenWord = new char[m_wordSize];** You are not leaving space for the null terminator

Comment: important note: `strlen` does not count the null terminator. The arrays you make based on `m_wordSize` will be one character too short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you allocate `m_chosenWord`, you allocate `m_wordSize` characters. However, in

```
strcpy_s(m_chosenWord, m_wordSize + 1, m_wordsArray[m_wordNumber]);
```

You are writing `m_wordSize + 1` characters. In the initial allocation, you want to add the `+1` as well.